# compare two files except first bytes of each lines with shell command

Tags: shell, diff, cmp

I have two log files with every line starting by the time. I'd like to compare the files except for this time part.

for exemple :

*file1.og*

```
[20220201_133108] abc
[20220201_133108] defg
[20220201_133108] hi
[20220201_133108] jkl
```

*file2.og*

```
[20220202_172431] abc
[20220202_172431] defg
[20220202_172431] hi
[20220202_172431] jkl
```

they are identical, except for the time part, so would like to use something like `diff [option to skip first bytes] file1.log file2.log` that would output that they are identical, a little bit like the `-i` option of `cmp`, but for each lines

I don't know how to do that, I've read the man of `diff` and `cmp` and maybe I missed something, but it doesn't seems like it's an existing option ?

In other hands, I don't see how I could use some `sed` or `awk` action to modify the file before comparing it, since diff is expecting a file, or a directory, not the output of a command ? Except of course to create temporary files, which I hope is not necessary

Comment: If you can handle Bash: `diff <(cut -d \  -f 2 file1) <(cut -d \  -f 2 file2)`

Comment: hoooo process substitution, great ! https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html thx :)

Comment: Process substitution is relatively easy to simulate with named pipes, though, if `bash` *isn't* an option.

Comment: in this case, bash is fine for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can handle Bash, you could use [*process substitution*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
$ diff <(cut -d \  -f 2 file1) <(cut -d \  -f 2 file2)
```